# pst-asr does not work with LuaLaTeX/ConTeXt

Tags: luatex, pstricks, context, pst-asr

When I try to compile the following code:

```
%LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-asr}
\begin{document}
\asr \4ki:p\endasr
\end{document}
```

I get this:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks 
                         _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.7 \asr \4
         ki:p\endasr
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

The same happens with ConTeXt:

```
%ConTeXt-mkiv
\input pst-asr
\starttext
\asr \4ki:p\endasr
\stoptext
```

I get:

```
tex error       > tex error on line 888 in file /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex: ! Missing \endcsname inserted

<to be read again> 
\bgroup 
\71>t #1->\bgroup 
                  \let \nextnextnext \egroup \def \next #1#1{\def \next {\ac...
\pgfmath@namedef #1->\expandafter \def \csname #1
                                                 \endcsname 
\pgfmathdeclareoperator ...th@operator@\string #1}
                                                  {#1}\pgfmath@namedef {pgfm...
l.888 ...areoperator{||}{or}        {2}{infix} {200}

878     \pgfmathdeclareoperator{^}{pow}     {2}{infix}{900}
879     
880     \pgfmathdeclareoperator{<} {}       {1}{prefix} {1}
881     
882     \pgfmathdeclareoperator{>} {greater}   {2}{infix} {250}
883     \pgfmathdeclareoperator{<} {less}      {2}{infix} {250}
884     \pgfmathdeclareoperator{==}{equal}     {2}{infix} {250}
885     \pgfmathdeclareoperator{>=}{notless}   {2}{infix} {250}
886     \pgfmathdeclareoperator{<=}{notgreater}{2}{infix} {250}
887     \pgfmathdeclareoperator{&&}{and}       {2}{infix} {200}
888 >>  \pgfmathdeclareoperator{||}{or}        {2}{infix} {200}
889     \pgfmathdeclareoperator{!=}{notequal}  {2}{infix} {250}
890     \pgfmathdeclareoperator{!} {not}       {1}{prefix}{975}
891     \pgfmathdeclareoperator{?} {ifthenelse}{3}{infix} {100}
892     \pgfmathdeclareoperator{:} {@@collect}  {2}{infix}{101}
893     
894     \pgfmathdeclareoperator{!}{factorial}{1}{postfix}{800}% Must be defined after prefix ! operator.
895     \pgfmathdeclareoperator{r}{deg}      {1}{postfix}{600}
896     
897     \pgfmathdeclareoperator{,}{@collect}   {2}{infix}  {10}
898     \pgfmathdeclareoperator{[}{@startindex}{2}{prefix} {7}
?
```

Is there a fix for these issues or should I give up on pst-asr?

Comment: I don't see any relation. pst-asr works well with XeLaTeX.

Comment: You are right, this error is reproducible on my machine.

Comment: @JairoAraujo: `luatex` and `xetex` are completely different.

Answer (score 3):

For `lualatex` use

```
%LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf-lua}
\usepackage{pst-asr}
\begin{document}
\begin{postscript}
\asr \4ki:p\endasr
\end{postscript}
\end{document}
```

and run it with `lualatex --shell-escape <filename>`

[image]

And for ConTeXt use

```
%ConTeXt-mkiv
\usemodule[pstricks]
\starttext
\startPSTRICKS
\input pst-asr
\asr \4ki:p\endasr
\stopPSTRICKS
\stoptext
```

However, using `xelatex` is the easiest way

Comment: Neither works. LuaLaTeX outputs diminute letters in the ASR, whereas ConTeXt doesn't show any ASR at all.

Comment: See my output with running `lualatex --shell-escape test.tex`. I have an up-to-date TL2019